# Bash: For Loop & save each output as a new column in a csv

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a folder with a mixture of files types (.bam, .bam.bai, and .log).  I created a for loop to perform two commands on each of the .bam files.  My current code direct the output of each command into a separate csv files, because I could not figure out how to direct the outputs to separate columns.

TYIA!

**Question 1**
I want to export the output from the commands into the same csv.  How can I alter my code so that the output from my first command is saved as the first column of a csv, and the output from my second command is saved as the second column of the same csv.

**Question 2**
What is the name of the syntax used to select files in a for loop?  For instance, the * in *.bam represents a wildcard. Is this regex?  I had a tough time trying to alter this so that only *.bam files were selected for the for loop (and .bam.bai were excluded).  I ended up with *[.bam] by guessing and empirically testing my outputs.  Are there any websites that do a good job of explaining this syntax and provide lots of examples (coder level: newbie)

**Current Code**

```
> ~/Desktop/Sample_Names.csv
> ~/Desktop/Read_Counts.csv

echo "Sample" | cat - > ~/Desktop/Sample_Names.csv
echo "Total_Reads" | cat - > ~/Desktop/Read_Counts.csv

for file in *[.bam]
do
  samtools view -c $file >> ~/Desktop/Read_Counts.csv
  gawk -v RS="^$" '{print FILENAME}' $file >> ~/Desktop/Sample_Names.csv
done
```

**Current Outputs (truncated)**

```
>Sample_Names.csv
| Sample       |
|--------------|
| B40-JV01.bam |
| B40-JV02.bam |
| B40-JV03.bam |

>Read_Counts.csv
| Total_Reads |
|-------------|
| 3835555     |
| 4110463     |
| 144558      |
```

**Desired Output**

```
>Combined_Outputs.csv
| Sample       | Total_Reads |
|--------------|-------------|
| B40-JV01.bam | 3835555     |
| B40-JV02.bam | 4110463     |
| B40-JV03.bam | 144558      |
```

Comment: They're called globs or wildcard patterns. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns

Comment: `gawk -v RS="^$" '{print FILENAME}' $file` = `echo $file` for non-empty files. Not sure what you were going for with that gawk command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```bash
echo "Sample,Total_Reads" > Combined_Outputs.csv
for file in *.bam; do
    printf "%s,%s\n" "$file" "$(samtools view -c "$file")"
done >> Combined_Outputs.csv
```

Print one line for each file, and move the output redirection outside of the loop for efficiency.

Comment: Thank you, this works!  Can't say I understand the syntax, though.  Is the semicolon in *.bam; part of the glob syntax?  Is %s also part of glob?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JVGen The semicolon is part of the `for` loop syntax. And the %s's are `printf` format specifiers. Nothing to do with globs.

Comment: How does "*.bam" specify ".bam" while excluding ".bam.bai" files?  I thought using *.bam alone would give me issues, but it seems to work!

Comment: @JVGen you seem to be confusing regexps with globbing patterns, see the reference [Shawn provided earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72646610/bash-for-loop-save-each-output-as-a-new-column-in-a-csv#comment128323677_72646610).